# How can i read cookies in asp.net mvc method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` and want to read cookies ,for that purpose write in cookies with this code:

```
Cookies.SaveCookies(validate);
```

not wan't  read that cookies in this method:

```
public static int CookiesReturn()
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["userName"] != null)
                return  Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["userName"].Value);

        }
```

but in the get error on `Request.Cookies`:

> Can not resolve Request

and too in this line `Server.HtmlEncode...` get this error:

> Can not resolve Request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `Controller` class has a public property called `HttpContext`(see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext.aspx)).Try prefixing it with `System.Web`.
**Example** `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[cookieName]`.

So your code something like

```
 public static int CookiesReturn()
 {
   HttpCookie cookie =HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["userName"];
   if (cookie  != null)
   string username = Server.HtmlEncode(cookie.Value);
  }
```

You can more information about cookie in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link.